# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metaclass'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I use python 3.9 in pycharm and try to import packages, I get the error.
The problem occurs after running to the second line of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

This is the output from the console

```
D:\Download\anaconda3\envs\py39\python.exe "D:/Download/JetBrains/PyCharm 2023.1.2/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 11881 --file "D:\proj2\Demo code.py" 
Connected to pydev debugger (build 231.9011.38)
2023-11-27 18:20:56.514016: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Download\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.
2023-11-27 18:21:08.537061: W external/local_tsl/tsl/lib/monitoring/collection_registry.cc:81] Trying to register 2 metrics with the same name: /tensorflow/api/keras/optimizers. The old value will be erased in order to register a new one. Please check if you link the metric more than once, or if the name is already used by other metrics.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Download\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 485, in <module>
    importlib.import_module("keras.src.optimizers")
  File "D:\Download\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "D:\Download\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras import distribute
  File "D:\Download\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\keras\distribute\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from keras.distribute import sidecar_evaluator
  File "D:\Download\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\keras\distribute\sidecar_evaluator.py", line 22, in <module>
    from keras.optimizers.optimizer_experimental import (
  File "D:\Download\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras.optimizers.legacy import adadelta as adadelta_legacy
  File "D:\Download\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\legacy\adadelta.py", line 17, in <module>
    from keras.optimizers.optimizer_v2 import adadelta
  File "D:\Download\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\adadelta.py", line 21, in <module>
    from keras.optimizers.optimizer_v2 import optimizer_v2
  File "D:\Download\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 103, in <module>
    @keras_export("keras.optimizers.Optimizer", metaclass=abc.ABCMeta)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metaclass'
python-BaseException
```

I tried to bring tensorflow up to date

> conda install tensorflow

Comment: Which versions of these packages do you have? How did you install them?

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the reply. I am using tensorflow 2.15.0 and keras 2.15.0. I think I used conda install tensorflow to install these packages. But I can't remember if I used pip install or just clicked the install button that pops up in the pycharm interface.

Comment: Do you get the same error when using "from keras.models import Sequential"? I ommitted tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are Facing an error related to the metaclass argument in python.In your case, the error occurs when TensorFlow tries to import Keras modules. This could be due to a version mismatch between TensorFlow, Keras, and possibly other related libraries.

You need to check that you are using the compatible version of tensorflow
and Keras. Some of the versions are designed to work with keras. You need to check your tensorflow and keras version.

Use this command to update tensorflow and keras:-

> pip install --upgrade tensorflow keras

**Check Python Version:-** Check that you are using the latest version or compatibility version of python.

Note:- You can follow this tensorflow original [documents](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)  for your referance.